# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'

Tags: sql-server-2012

I keep getting a error message when I try to use the between operator in SQL Server 2012.

```
select *
from Sales.Store
where SalesPersonID>283
order by Name between 'g' and'j' desc;
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Has anyone seen this? Any suggestions

Comment: What are you trying to do? Order by the Boolean result?

Comment: I am searching AdventureWorks2012 for the store names in the table and I only need the ones which start with G-J.

Comment: So that is totally wrong then. It should be in the `where` not `order by`

Comment: Thank you. I moved the between to the where clause and it worked.  select *
from Sales.Store
where SalesPersonID>283 and Name between 'g' and 'j'
order by Name desc;

Comment: You should use `like` not between.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't allow you to order by a Boolean you can use

```
select *
from Sales.Store
where SalesPersonID>283
order by IIF(Name between 'g' and'j', 0,1);
```

But `between` probably doesn't have the semantics you want anyway.

You could use `IIF(Name LIKE '[g-j]%',0,1)` instead if you want to include all names beginning with j in the group ordered first.

But after your comment this is what you need

```
select *
from Sales.Store
where SalesPersonID>283 AND Name LIKE '[g-j]%';
```

You should not use `between` as that would only include names that were exactly "j" not all those beginning with "j".